# Why aren't NaN-s ingored in pgfplots' axis?

Tags: pgfplots

Why doesn't `\addplot`ignore `NaN`s I used to break columns? MATLAB `plot` function correctly ignores them, so I think the columns are OK. Moreover in `pgfplots` doc `NaN`s are suggested to be used when such breaks are needed.

Oh, my intent is to create a grid (I don't use the grids of pgfplots for other reasons not connected with colors and appearence)

My MWE is the following (The file `.dat` is [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/17093893/griglia_psi.dat))

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{book}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage[super]{nth}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,decorations,patterns,shapes.arrows}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{tikzscale}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotscreateplotcyclelist{rgblist}{%
{red,mark=*},
{green,mark=square*},
{blue,mark=triangle*}}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
\usepackage[font=small,
            format=hang,
            labelfont={sf,bf},
            tableposition=top,
            figureposition=bottom]{caption}


\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[p]

    \centering
   \begin{tikzpicture}
      \begin{axis}
         \addplot[black] table[x=X1,y=Y1] {immagini/data/griglia_psi.dat};
         \addplot[black] table[x=X2,y=Y2] {immagini/data/griglia_psi.dat};
      \end{axis}
   \end{tikzpicture}

    \caption{Accuracy accuracy aaaaaccuracy accuracy accuracy accuracy accuracy accuracy accuracy accuracy accuracy accuracy accuracy accuracy accuracy accuracy accuracy accuracy accuracy accuracy accuracy accuracy accuracy accuracy accuracy accuracy.}
    \label{fig:accuracy}
\end{figure}


\end{document}
```

Comment: It's matlab's weirdness that it accepts Nans as column breaks. NaN is a valid point input and pgfplots discards such points in the input stream. Pgfplots even recognize newlines, tabs, double backslashes why would you even use NaNs to break columns?

Comment: Mmm, ok. So how should I produce the dat file for my purpose? (please, consider I cannot give in line data and that I produce them with MATLAB)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `pgfplots` manual, there is a section on "Interrupted Plots"; to do what you want you need to set the option `unbounded coords=jump` as in the following code:

```
  \begin{axis}[unbounded coords=jump]
     \addplot[black] table[x=X1,y=Y1] {immagini/data/griglia_psi.dat};
     \addplot[black] table[x=X2,y=Y2] {immagini/data/griglia_psi.dat};
  \end{axis}
```

Comment: Oh, that's exactly what I want! ;)