# Plot polynomial function with tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, tikz-pic

I'm trying to plot this function : `f(x)=(x^2+3x+9)/(3x)`.
I'm having an error saying that I can't divide 9 by 0, is there any solution please?

here is my code :

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
            \draw[step=0.5cm,cyan,very thin] (-1,-1) grid (5,6);
            \draw[black, ->] (-1,0) -- (5,0); 
            \draw[black, ->] (0,-1) -- (0,6);
            \draw[thick, black, ->] (0,0) -- (0.5,0); 
            \draw[thick, black, ->] (0,0) -- (0,0.5);
            \draw [scale=0.5, domain=0:10,samples=25, teal] plot (\x,{(9+(\x)^2+3*\x)/(3*\x)}) ;
            \draw [scale=0.5, domain=-2:10, smooth, variable=\x, blue] plot ({\x}, {-2/3*\x+5}); 
            \filldraw[blue] (3,0.5) node[anchor=south] {$d$};
            \filldraw[teal] (4,2) node[anchor=south] {$\mathcal{C}$};
            \filldraw[black] (3,1.75) node[anchor=south west] {A};
            \filldraw[black] (3,1.75) node[] {$\times$};
            \filldraw[black] (0,0.25) node[anchor=east] {$\overrightarrow{i}$};
            \filldraw[black] (0.25,0) node[ anchor=north] {$\overrightarrow{j}$};
            \filldraw[black] (5,0) node[ anchor=south east] {$x$};
            \filldraw[black] (0,6) node[ anchor=north west] {$y$};
            \foreach \x in {-1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}
            \draw ({\x cm/2},2pt) -- ({\x cm/2},-2pt) node[anchor=north] {$\x$};
            \foreach \y in {2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11}
            \draw (2pt, {\y cm/2}) -- (-2pt, {\y cm/2}) node[anchor=east]{$\y$};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

here is the error :

> Package PGF Math Error: You've asked me to divide `9.0' by` 0.0', but
> I cannot divide any number by `0.0' (in '{(9+(0)^2+3*0)/(3*0)}'). ...
> teal] plot (\x,{(9+(\x)^2+3*\x)/(3*\x)})

**EDIT**
The graphic I'm trying to draw :
[image]

Comment: This is a mathematical problem: when you divide a nonzero number by zero, the result is not defined as a number, so where do you want to draw that result?

Comment: Take a look at the code, I'm trying to draw the function I mentioned above

Comment: Unrelated: this function is not  a polynomial function, but a *rational* function (quotient of two polynomials).

Comment: @Houcine: ok, but your function doesn't make sense when $x=0$, since the value of the function is $9/0$. You can't divide by zero (a mathematical issue, not a TeX problem). For $x$ near $0$, your function takes on values as large positive and as large negative as you like. So the picture needs to be drawn on infinitely tall paper. What do you want the computer to do about that? Maybe the simplest thing is to change the domain to 1:10 instead of 0:10.

Comment: Changing the domain can be a solution but I need to draw it as the picture I just added

Answer (score 2):

The green polynomial Function has the wrong domain. If you set the x-value to 0, the y-value will be infinite. For x=0.2 the y-value is 16.067. That is more than the 11 on your y-axis. So set the domain to 0.2:10. Then the plot of the green line will exceed the limits of your y-axis and will look the same as in the added picture.

Answer (score 1):

To get around this problem, one uses `pgfplots`, with which the picture shown (for the domain 0 to 9) can easily be generated.

However, the problem also reappears when drawing over definition gaps (in the form of an ugly connecting line). So in general you will have to plot the function piecewise (just like you have to do with "TikZ-only").

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5pt, varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex]
\begin{axis}[%axis equal,
axis lines=middle, 
xmin=-0.0, xmax=9.5,
ymin=-0.5, ymax=11.75,
xtick={1,...,9},
ytick={1,...,11},
grid=major,
samples=222,
xlabel={$x$},
xlabel style = {anchor=south east},
ylabel={$y$},
ylabel style = {anchor=east},
enlarge x limits={abs=0.5},
]
\addplot[draw=green!55!black, thick, mark=none, 
domain=0:9]{(x^2+3*x+9)/(3*x)};    
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}



\begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex]
\begin{axis}[x=5mm, y=5mm,
axis lines=middle, 
xmin=-9.5, xmax=9.5,
ymin=-11.75, ymax=11.75,
xtick={-9,...,9},
ytick={-11,...,11},
grid=major,
samples=222,
xlabel={$x$},
xlabel style = {anchor=south east},
ylabel={$y$},
ylabel style = {anchor=east},
]
\addplot[draw=green!55!black, thick, mark=none, 
domain=0.0:9]{(x^2+3*x+9)/(3*x)};    
\addplot[draw=green!55!black, thick, mark=none, 
domain=-9:-0.1]{(x^2+3*x+9)/(3*x)};    
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Or you can jump over unbound coordinates, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/271190/38080 (not tried, but it should work...)

Comment: I tested `unbounded coords=jump`, but I got this silly line 'x=0'.  Sometimes that works (maybe with y=abs(x) or something). My experience is that one often have to draw it piecewise again.